# How can I programmatically determine Windows PE version?

Tags: windows, winpe

My application needs to determine whether it is running on Windows PE.

Neither the deprecated [GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa) function nor the preferred alternative [Version Helper APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis) offer any indication whether I am operating on WinPE, only indicating the version of the OS.

[This reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-apps) lists the compatible APIs for WinPE, so I need to be able limit my app to those APIs.

How can I programmatically determine from my App whether I am on WinPE, and which PE version is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to determine whether you are running WinPE or not, you can check for the presence of the key `MiniNT` in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control` or `HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Control`. If it is present, you are on WinPE 2.x or higher.

Cited in [MSDN docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/whats-new-in-windows-pe-s14), you can see which version of Windows PE youare running at the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinPE`. That reference also gives a table of features and functionality each version will provide you.

For very old versions of Windows/WinPE before 2.0, check the version of `%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\FACTORY.EXE`.